# Hom press second button with id:inf?

Tags: junit, nativeapplication, testdroid

I use Testdroid, it based on junit3.
Command:

```
solo.clickOnView(solo.findViewById("cc.app.R.id.inf"));
```

open first button with id:`inf`

1. what command need use to press on second(third and more) button
   with id:`inf`.
2. how select area/layout, where junit try found element with
    id:`inf`, something like that:

Here use command to chose LinearLayout by index and then

```
solo.clickOnView(solo.findViewById("cc.app.R.id.inf"));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get/find LinearLayout view by index with methods:

```
getView(int id,int index)
getView(Class<T> viewClass, int index)
...
```

Then you can use method(s):

```
getViews(android.view.View parent)
getCurrentViews(Class<T> classToFilterBy, android.view.View parent)
```

which returns list of views, so filtering must be done by your code/helper method.